# How can I add a UIView as a subview of UIViewController when a button clicked?

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller

In my app I need to add a UIView dynamically whenever user taps on a button in my main UIViewController. How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a new method in your view controller with this signature: `-(IBAction) buttonTapped:(id)sender`. Save your file. Go to Interface Builder and connect your button to this method (control-click and drag from your button to the view controller [probably your File's owner] and select the `-buttonTapped` method).
Then implement the method:

```
-(IBAction) buttonTapped:(id)sender {
    // create a new UIView
    UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,100,100)];

    // do something, e.g. set the background color to red
    newView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    // add the new view as a subview to an existing one (e.g. self.view)
    [self.view addSubview:newView];

    // release the newView as -addSubview: will retain it
    [newView release];
}
```