# Adding subview doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, xcode

```
- (IBAction)add {

    UIImageView *must = [UIImageView alloc];
    [must setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"themustache.png"]];  
    must.center = CGPointMake(0, 0);

    [self.view addSubview:must];
    [must bringSubviewToFront:self.view];
}
```

When I press a button it should add a mustache, but it doesn't

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994174/how-to-add-a-uiview-as-a-subview-of-uiviewcontrollr-when-a-button-clicked-on-uivi).
Hope this helps.

Comment: And add NSLog() in your function, and see if it gets called (see log on console.) Try it.

Comment: yes it is getting called

Comment: are you calling this function from MainAppDelegate?

Comment: no i am  not im calling from a  uiviewcontroller subclass

Answer (score 1):

```
- (IBAction)add {

    UIImageView *must = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];

    [must setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"themustache.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [self.view addSubview:must];

    [must release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you telling must to bring its parent to the front? Try this:
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:must];

Comment: @user885074: No need to call `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:must]`.

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure image named themustache.png exists ..
This one worked for me ..

```
-(IBAction)add {  
UIImageView *must=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,50, 50)];  
must.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"themustache.png"];  
[self.view addSubview:must];  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it will help you.
First of all, set the frame of UIImageView and add that imageview into view, it will work fine.

```
-(IBAction)add  
{
    UIImageView *must = [UIImageView alloc];
    must.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 50.0, 262.0, 34.0);
    must.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [must setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"themustache.png"]];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:must];

}
```

Comment: @user894725: check for the png, if its not there in resource folder.

Comment: is its image place in resource folder?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the button is connected to the right action in Interface Builder.  Also put this in your add method NSLog(@"Pressed");.  If it is connected you should see the Pressed message displayed in the console every time you press the button.

Comment: yes the console does execute the NSLog i can see the pressed, so the button does work

Comment: Only other thing i can suggest is to remove must.center = CGPointMake(0, 0);.  That could be positioning it off the screen.

Comment: @ms83: `must.center = CGPointMake(0, 0);` is okay. It will make the center of the image exactly at the top left corner of the screen. That's it. So, the user will be able to see only the forth (down right) part of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know, whether its working or not,

```
- (IBAction)add {
UIImage *mustImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"themustache.png"];
UIImageView *must = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:mustImage];
[self.view addSubview:must];  
[mustImage release];
[must release];
}
```

or this,

```
- (IBAction)add {
CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f);
UIImageView *must = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
[must setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"themustache.png"]];
[self.view addSubview:must];  
[must release];
}
```

Try, `window` instead of `self.view` if you are calling the function right from **AppDelegate.m**.
Both of the above, must work for you.

Comment: dont work still, itsprobably my image even though iyts the samename