# Unable to set property of a UIViewController ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a view controller which extends UIViewController.

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *phoneTxt;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *data;
@end
```

However when I try to set the property of the view controller by:

```
MyViewController *vvc = (MyViewController *)[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyVC"];
vvc.data = data;
```

I get following error:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController setData:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I have checked, the view controller is not nil and I have synthesized the property data in MyViewController.m

```
@synthesize data = _data;
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Are you sure that 

`MyViewController *vvc = (MyViewController *)[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyVC"];`

line of code gives you instance of `MyViewController` class ? Looking at your error it might be returning `UIViewController` class instance.

Comment: In your storyboard you forgot to change the class of your viewController, take a look

Comment: The issue got resolved, but it seems like my app now enters an infinite loop. :/ it keeps calling [NSLocalizableString length]

Comment: I was trying to fix this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32736496/instantiating-modal-view-controller-freezes-the-app?noredirect=1#comment53323268_32736496

Comment: Just so you know you don't need to do the `@synthesize` anymore this will be done automatically for you when you declare your property. Bin `@synthesize data = _data;` off completely it isn't need and is just a waste of space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you probably forgot to set the proper class for your view controller (File's Owner) in your storyboard/xib, so it probably gets instantiated as a raw `UIWievController`.

[image]